# JavaScript: Nesting objects, and accessing the parent(s)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to nest javascript objects:

```
Manager (singleton)
    Tab Group
        Tab
            Trigger (Button)
            Target (Panel)
        Tab
            Trigger
            Target
        Tab
            Trigger
            Target
    Tab Group
        ...
```

In the `Trigger` and `Target` objects, I need to have access to the parent `Tab`, grandparent `Tab Group`, and root `Manager`.

**One option: Navigate 1 level at a time:**

```
// in a Trigger
this.tab
this.tab.group
this.tab.group.manager

// in a Tab
this.group
this.group.manager

// and Group
this.manager
```

**Another option:  I could make them all accessible directly:**

```
// in a Trigger
this.tab
this.group
this.manager
```

Do either of these make sense?  It seems like this would be a common problem.  Do any libraries like Underscore or Backbone have a better solution?  **Is it common practice to pass the parent to the child in the constructor??**

EDIT:  After posting, and rethinking, Option 1 seems acceptable.  Can anyone confirm?

Comment: An object has no concept of a "parent". A reference to an object can be assigned to a variable or an object property, the object has no idea how it was accessed. So if you want to create relationships, you have to do it explicitly in the code (e.g. assign a *parent* property that is a reference to a "parent" object).

Comment: passing parent to child constructor is fine. This in fact is required and also makes sense for parent child relationship and navigation.